# $\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{\sqrt{5x-4-x^2}}{\lfloor x \rfloor - 3}= 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Is the limit $\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{\sqrt{5x-4-x^2}}{\lfloor x \rfloor  - 3}= 0$?

I was trying to solve this using the extremes.

$$\lim_{x \to 4^{+}} \frac{\sqrt{5x-4-x^2}}{\lfloor x \rfloor  - 3}$$ is equal to zero because the denominator is different from 0 but
$$\lim_{x \to 4^{-}} \frac{\sqrt{5x-4-x^2}}{\lfloor x \rfloor  - 3}$$ is $\frac{0}{0}$

so I thought in using L'Hopital but I was doubtful if i can, because the floor function is not continuous in $[n,n+1]$.

Comment: Do you mean to take the limit as $n$ approaches 4 or as $x$ approaches 4?

Comment: When $n>4$, $5x-4-x^2=-(x-1)(x-4)<0$

Comment: When $ 3 \leq x < 4, \frac{\sqrt{(5x-4-x^2)}}{\lfloor x \rfloor  - 3}$ is division by zero and is therefore undefined.

Comment: You need to fix:  n=x?

Comment: @Kman3 sorry i dont understand your question.

Comment: @AdamRubinson so the limit doens't exist?

Comment: @herbsteinberg sorry for that, i mean the floor funtion is not continuo in the extreme of a intervalue or is a mistake?

Comment: Assuming your question was $ lim_{x \to 4} \frac{\sqrt{(5x-4-x^2)}}{\lfloor x \rfloor  - 3}$ rather than $ lim_{n \to 4} \frac{\sqrt{(5x-4-x^2)}}{\lfloor x \rfloor  - 3}$ then yes, the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression in the square root needs to be non-negative:

$$5x-4-x^2=\tfrac94-(x-\tfrac52)^2\geq0$$

$$(x-\tfrac52)^2\leq\tfrac94$$

$$|x-\tfrac52|\leq\tfrac32$$

$$-\tfrac32\leq x-\tfrac52\leq\tfrac32$$

$$1\leq x\leq4$$

On the other hand, the denominator needs to be non-zero:

$$\lnot\big[\,\lfloor x\rfloor-3=0\,\big]$$

$$\lnot\big[\,3\leq x<4\,\big]$$

$$x<3\quad\text{or}\quad x\geq4$$

Combining these, we find that the domain of the function is $[1,3)\cup\{4\}$; that is,

$$1\leq x<3\quad\text{or}\quad x=4$$

There is nothing in the domain around $x=4$, so the left and right limits are both undefined.